# Remove text starting form a specific character in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a text document that looks like this:

2321.00 / 2321.00
342.44 / 4324

I need to remove everything starting with the first space and do it for every line.
The result should look like this:

2321.00
342.44

thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Select `Search` > `Replace`
2. Tick the box `Regular expression`
3. Use the following regex in the `Find what` field

   \s/\s[\d.]+$
4. Hit `Replace All`

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+/\h+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       # beginning of line
.+      # 1 or more any character
/       # a slash
\h+     # 1 or more horizontal spaces
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]